# Is this statement true or false?numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

***The counting numbers are a subset of the whole numbers.*** 
Can you explain too, please?

Comment: What is "counting numbers" *for you*? Define.

Comment: Compare the "informal" definition of [Counting Numbers](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/counting-number.html) with that of  [Whole Numbers](https://www.mathsisfun.com/whole-numbers.html).

Comment: If A and B are sets of things, then all of the things that are in A are also found in B.  All counting numbers (1,2,3,4,5......) are also whole numbers.  So counting numbers is a subset of whole numbers.  Not all whole numbers (e.g 0 and -1) are counting numbers.  (if you agree that zero is not a counting number)

Comment: @DonAntonio I'd take 'counting numbers' to mean the same as ordinal numbers, integers >= 1 - you could argue if zero is a counting number I guess.  I'd imagine a whole numbers is integers

Comment: @AndrewDeighton I'd also take the same as "counting numbers", yet the OP hasn't yet addressed this doubt.

Comment: @Andrew "whole numbers" are the union of counting number and the set $\{0\}$.  It is the set of integers $\mathbb Z$ in which the additive inverses  of "counting numbers" are include with Whole numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$W$, the set of *whole numbers,* includes all elements of the set $C$ of counting numbers plus zero. That is $W = C\cup \{0\}$.

So, yes, $C\subseteq W$, because for any number $c \in C,$ we also have  $c \in W$

Note that if the counting numbers also include $0$, then $W = C,$ but it is should also the case that  $C \subseteq W$ still holds true.